# Is there an Agroal configuration for the initial SQL?

Tags: quarkus

I'm setting up a connection pool using Quarkus. I want to know whether there is an Agroal configuration for the initial SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't directly on the Agroal extension but there is one on the Hibernate ORM one.

You can use, the following property (default to import.sql):

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.sql-load-script=import.sql
```

The configuration reference can be found here: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-guide#properties-to-refine-your-hibernate-orm-configuration